# How to clear this Database connection error in a JSP program?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to link my JSP login file to MySQL database, but I am getting the error as below. I also imported MySQL-connector jar file into the project. I have no idea of why I am getting this error. Please help me in rectifying my error.

My Code:

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    String userid = request.getParameter("uname");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/college",
            "root", "root");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from studentdata where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");
    if (rs.next()) {
        session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
        //out.println("welcome " + userid);
        //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
        response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
    } else {
        out.println("Invalid password <a href='index.jsp'>try again</a>");
    }
%>
```

Error Message:

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 5

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 5

2: <%
3:     String userid = request.getParameter("uname");    
4:     String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
5:     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
6:     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/college",
7:             "root", "root");
8:     Statement st = con.createStatement();


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



root cause 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
```

Comment: can you check whether its there in your runtime classpath ?

Comment: Yeah, it is in my classpath @AmitK

Comment: i mean runtime classpath.

Comment: Is it 'Environment Variables'? @AmitK

Comment: are you using maven in your project ? putting mysql-connector jar manually is not the recommended way

Comment: I am not using maven, I directly added mysql-connector into project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're getting this error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Suggestions:

1.- is the driver mysql****.jar in the folder WEB-INF/lib ?

2.- did you registered it in your classpath?

Hope it helps

Comment: 1.- is the driver mysql****.jar in the folder WEB-INF/lib? NO

Comment: can you put the jar http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm (well not this version, use the version of your mysql) in the lib folder, and add to your class path that must work

Comment: Above jsp file is executed, but error in another jsp file, can I ask it here?

Comment: Did you get to managed the connection? I don't know if you can ask here or you must create another topic for it, i guess you should create another topic but I really don't know, what is the error anyway?

Comment: I think the connection error is solved. I am unable to ask another question as only one question per day. It is showing an error msg as 'MySQLSyntaxErrorException', but I think my syntax is correct.

Comment: Oh I see, well that error could be for this line: st.executeQuery("select * from studentdata where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'"); Well not 100% sure, can you share the log please?

Comment: You can have a glance at registration.jsp code from this [link](http://www.javaknowledge.info/login-and-registration-example-in-jsp-with-session/)

Comment: Error message: `javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Comment: The problem is in your query why don't you create a String s = "select * from studentdata where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'""; (use scape \ for the ") once you've done that, print it in order to see how does the sql look like, and paste it in your database manager , i mean execute it, maybe you're writing someting wrong, and you can check it, I'd do that

Comment: Actually, this query is to add user values in studentdata table from the user given details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142000/discussion-between-yussef-and-jitendra-reddy).